# Red Black Tree Algorithm not going through rotation

Tags: java, c#, data-structures, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I am using the following algorithm. The only problem is that at runtime parent.left or parent.right are being resolved to null and hence it is not going in the rotations in method insertFix(). I tried adding the following code when adding an item

```
/*if (parent != null)
                {
                    if (value > parent.value)
                    {
                        parent.right = newNode;
                    }
                    else {
                        parent.left = newNode;
                    }
                }*/
```

However this is causing a stackoverflow Exception. Any help on how to resolve this please?

```
 public void insertRBT(int value)
    {
        root=insertNode(root, value,null);
        count += 1;   
    }


    protected BNode insertNode(BNode rt, int value, BNode parent)
    {
        BNode grandParent, greatGrandParent;
        if (rt == null)
        {
            BNode newNode = new BNode(value, parent);
            parent = newNode.parent;

            /*if (parent != null)
            {
                if (value > parent.value)
                {
                    parent.right = newNode;
                }
                else {
                    parent.left = newNode;
                }
            }*/
            if (count > 0)
            {
                newNode.red = true;
            }
            else
            {
                newNode.red = false;
            }
            //added

            insertedNode = newNode;
            grandParent = null;
            greatGrandParent = null;
            insertFix(newNode,parent,grandParent,greatGrandParent);
            return newNode;
        }
        else if (value.CompareTo(rt.value) < 0)
        {
            rt.left = insertNode(rt.left, value, rt);
            return rt;
        }else //if(value.CompareTo(rt.value)> 0)
        {
            rt.right = insertNode(rt.right, value, rt);
            return rt;
        }
    }

    private void insertFix(BNode node, BNode parent, BNode grandParent, BNode greatGrandParent)
    {

       if(count>0)
            parent = node.parent;
        if(parent!=null)
            grandParent = GrandParent(node);
        BNode uncle = Uncle(node);
        if(grandParent!=null)
         greatGrandParent = grandParent.parent;

        if(grandParent!=null)
        {
            if (uncle != null && parent.red && uncle.red)
            {
                uncle.red = false;
                parent.red = false;
                grandParent.red = true;
                BNode higher = null;
                BNode stillhigher = null;
                if (greatGrandParent != null)
                {
                    higher = greatGrandParent.parent;
                } if (higher != null)
                {
                    stillhigher = higher.parent;
                }
                insertFix(grandParent, greatGrandParent, higher, stillhigher);
            } else if (uncle == null || parent.red && !uncle.red)
            {
                if (grandParent.right == parent && parent.right == node)
                {
                    parent.red = false;
                    grandParent.red = true;
                    if (greatGrandParent != null)
                    {
                        if (greatGrandParent.right == grandParent)
                        {
                            LeftRotate(grandParent);
                            greatGrandParent.right = grandParent;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            LeftRotate(grandParent);
                            greatGrandParent.left = grandParent;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LeftRotate(root);
                    }
                }
            } else if (grandParent.left == parent && parent.left == node)
            {
                parent.red = false;
                grandParent.red = true; //changed
                if(greatGrandParent!=null)
                {
                    if(greatGrandParent.right==grandParent)
                    {
                        RightRotate(grandParent);
                        greatGrandParent.right = grandParent;
                    }else
                    {
                        RightRotate(grandParent);
                        greatGrandParent.left = grandParent;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    RightRotate(root);
                }
            }else if(grandParent.right==parent && parent.left==node) //wasalt
            {
                node.red = false;
                grandParent.red = true; //changed
                RightRotate(parent);
                grandParent.right = parent;
                if(greatGrandParent!=null)
                {
                    if(greatGrandParent.right==grandParent)
                    {
                        LeftRotate(grandParent);
                        greatGrandParent.right = grandParent;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LeftRotate(grandParent);
                        greatGrandParent.left = grandParent;
                    }
                }else
                {
                    LeftRotate(root);
                }
            }else if(grandParent.left==parent && parent.right==node)
            {
                node.red = false;
                grandParent.red = true;
                LeftRotate(parent);
                grandParent.left = parent;
                if(greatGrandParent!=null)
                {
                    if(greatGrandParent.right == grandParent)
                    {
                        RightRotate(grandParent);
                        greatGrandParent.right = grandParent;
                    }else
                    {
                        RightRotate(grandParent);
                        greatGrandParent.left = grandParent;
                    }
                }else
                {
                    RightRotate(root);
                }
            }
            root.red = false;
        }
   }

    //GrandParent
    public BNode GrandParent(BNode node)
    {
        if ((node != null) && (node.parent != null))
        {
            return node.parent.parent;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    //Uncle
    public BNode Uncle(BNode node)
    {
        BNode gp = GrandParent(node);
        if (gp == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (node.parent == gp.left)
        {
            return gp.right;
        }
        else
        {
            return gp.left;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try making all the methods public and see if you have same issue.  If you are getting a stackoverflow exception is usually means you are in an endless loop.  You have a recursive algorithm and you are probably calling the same function over and over again without transversing through the tree.

Comment: I tried making all the methods public however, the problem persists. From what I debugged and understood, modifying the parent left and right pointers as I did, disrupted the flow of the BST

Comment: When you add a node you have to pass the current node 'this'.  You are passing 'rt' which is the parent.  You are missing a whole generation.